# My mocked method returns the same instance on each call, how do I get it to return a new instance?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

```
private mockedObject cpMock;

@Test
public void test() {

    Manager managerTest = new Manager(cpMock, size);

    Instance instance = new Instance(size);
    when(cpMock.requestInstance()).thenReturn(instance);

}
```

Comment: You know that your example code doesn't initialize that mock? Please make sure you always post a [mcve] to avoid confusing your readers.

Comment: Pardon the reopen, but this is a slightly different question: You're not just returning different instances (which `thenReturn` is good for), but you're specifically asking about creating new instances. An Answer would be good for that. (I'll answer below.)

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I'm trying to create new instances.

Answer (score 4):

There's an overload for `thenReturn`, which has a var-arg parameter:

```
when(cpMock.requestInstance())
   .thenReturn(instance, instance1, instance2, instance3);
```

According to its javadocs, it will return these objects in that order. From the 4th call on, `instance3` (last value) will be returned:

> Sets consecutive return values to be returned when the method is called. E.g:
>   `when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(1, 2, 3);`
>   
> Last return value in the sequence (in example: 3) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.

Answer (score 1):

`thenReturn` is good when all you're doing is returning a precomputed value. If you'd like to mock an instance to *do something* every time your method is called, then the right solution is an [Answer](https://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) (passed in with `thenAnswer` or `doAnswer`), which is a single-method interface that works well with Java 8. You can get details about the invocation (including its arguments) with its [InvocationOnMock](https://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html) parameter, and the return value of `Answer.answer` will act as the return value of the method.

This is also a good solution when you need your call to have side effects, like modifying its argument or calling a callback function.

```
when(cpMock.requestInstance()).thenAnswer(invocation => new Instance(size));
```

Without lambdas, the call is a little more verbose, but not too bad:

```
when(cpMock.requestInstance()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Instance>() {
  @Override public Instance answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    return new Instance(size));
  }
}
```